# How to address politely in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I wonder how to address politely someone in the terms of:

"How are you Mr. Cesar"

In Spanish (and Latin derived), they use the respectful form, *"usted, vous..."*

**Question**
How to address someone respectfully?

Comment: Sanchez: Welcome to the site. You need, "Conversational Latin" by Traupmann. It's freely available on the net. Lucky you!

Comment: Latin didn't have the T-V distinction of most later Romance languages, so you'd just use *tu* with everyone. I suspect people are reluctant to post answers because there really isn't much more to say than that.